# How to Distinguish Between IPv4 and IPv6 Packets Using Npcap Library in C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, ip

I am developing a desktop application on Windows that captures and processes packets from network interfaces of a network host. I am using the Npcap library with C++. Can anyone show me how I can determine whether a packet is IPv4 or IPv6?

This was the code I wrote after searching for a solution online:

```
    // check if packet is ipv4
    bool IsIpv4Packet(const u_char* packetData)
    {
       // Assuming Ethernet frame or Wi-Fi frame
        if ((packetData[EthernetHeaderSize - 2] == 0x08 && packetData[EthernetHeaderSize - 1] == 0x00) ||  // EtherType for IPv4
            (packetData[EthernetHeaderSize - 2] == 0x08 && packetData[EthernetHeaderSize - 1] == 0x06) ||  // EtherType for Wi-Fi (WEP)
            (packetData[EthernetHeaderSize - 2] == 0x08 && packetData[EthernetHeaderSize - 1] == 0x08) ||  // EtherType for Wi-Fi (WPA)
            (packetData[0] == 0x88 && packetData[1] == 0x8E)) {    // Type for Wi-Fi (802.1X)
            // It's an IPv4 packet
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // check if packet is ipv4
    bool IsIpv6Packet(const u_char* packetData)
    {
        // Assuming Ethernet frame or Wi-Fi frame
        if ((packetData[EthernetHeaderSize - 2] == 0x86 && packetData[EthernetHeaderSize - 1] == 0xDD) ||   // EtherType for IPv6
            (packetData[EthernetHeaderSize - 2] == 0x08 && packetData[EthernetHeaderSize - 1] == 0x06) ||  // EtherType for Wi-Fi (WEP)
            (packetData[EthernetHeaderSize - 2] == 0x08 && packetData[EthernetHeaderSize - 1] == 0x08) ||  // EtherType for Wi-Fi (WPA)
            (packetData[0] == 0x88 && packetData[1] == 0x8E)) {    // Type for Wi-Fi (802.1X)
            // It's an IPv6 packet
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    
    }
```

The code doesn't seem to determine whether a packet is IPv4 or IPv6 as intended.

Comment: 0x0800 and 0x86DD are [the correct EtherType values for IPv4 and IPv6, respectively](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ieee-802-numbers/ieee-802-numbers.xhtml)   Your "EtherType for Wi-Fi" is a mess and completely incorrect, it actually matches ARP traffic (only used for IPv4, IPv6 uses Neighbor Discovery Protocol instead)

Comment: Note also the copy-paste error in the comments (Both say `check if packet is ipv4`).  No wonder the programmer got the logic wrong when the comment was wrong ;)

Comment: Is there a better way i can perform the logic?

Comment: You have two possible issues -- searching for too many different EtherTypes values, and possibly searching in the wrong place (in case there's any VLAN tag or anything like that changing the structure of the Ethernet header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and was able to land on this solution which I know is little basic but works for me, Any addition to the solution will be much appreciated:

```
// Check if packet is IPv4
bool PacketCollector::IsIpv4Packet(const u_char* packetData, int linkType) 
{
    if (linkType == EthernetFrame) 
    {
        // Ethernet frame
        const uint16_t ethType = (packetData[12] << 8) | packetData[13];
        return ethType == 0x0800;  // IPv4 Ethernet frame

    }
    else if (linkType == WifiFrame) 
    {   // Wi-Fi frame (Assuming Wi-Fi data frames)
        // parse the data frame to check if it's IPv4
        // check the EtherType inside the data frame.
        const uint16_t etherType = (packetData[30] << 8) | packetData[31]; // Assuming Ethernet II frame
        return etherType == 0x0800;  // IPv4 EtherType

    }
    return false;
}

// Check if packet is IPv6
bool PacketCollector::IsIpv6Packet(const u_char* packetData, int linkType) 
{
    if (linkType == EthernetFrame)
    {
        // Ethernet frame
        const uint16_t ethType = (packetData[12] << 8) | packetData[13];
        return ethType == 0x86DD;  // IPv6 Ethernet frame

    }
    else if (linkType == WifiFrame)
    {   // Wi-Fi frame (Assuming Wi-Fi data frames)
        // parse the data frame to check if it's IPv6
        // check the EtherType inside the data frame.
        const uint16_t etherType = (packetData[30] << 8) | packetData[31]; // Assuming Ethernet II frame
        return etherType == 0x86DD; // Wi-Fi data frame for IPv6

    }
    return false;
}
```